# PHPUnit undefined function expectException

Tags: phpunit

I try to  run my test to test exception situation, but I get error -  undefined function expectException:

```
 public function testException($n)
    {
        $this->expectException(Exception::class);
        $this->expectExceptionMessage('Parameter n must be > 0');
        $task9 = new Source\Task9();
        $task9->tower_builder($n);
    }
```

And my composer.json file is:

```
{
"name": "codewars/pack",
"description": "Codewars project",
"type": "project",
"require": {
 "phpunit/phpunit": "5.5.*"
},
"autoload": {
"psr-4": {
  "Source\\": "src/"
 }
 }
 }
```

Comment: Do your test class extends `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase`?